# Custom loss function in keras to map input vectors of variable length to output vectors of variable lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a general question about supervised learning with keras that maps inputs to outputs. It is possible to vary the length of the input and output vectors by inserting some dummy variables that will not be considered in the mapping (or will be mapped to other dummy variables). So basically the mapping should look like this (v: value, d: dummy)

Input vector 1 [v,v,v,v,v] --> Output vector 1 [v,v,v,v,v]

Input vector 2 [v,v,v,v,v]--> Output vector 2 [v,v,v,v,v]

Input vector 3 [v,v,v,d,d] --> Output vector 3 [v,v,v,d,d]

Input vector 4 [v,v,d,d,d] -->  Output vector 4 [v,v,d,d,d]

Input vector 5 [v,d,d,d,d] -->  Output vector 5 [v,d,d,d,d]

The input and output vectors have a length of 5 with 5 values. However, sometimes only a vector of size e.g. 3 (which is basically a vector of length 5 with 2 dummy variables) should be mapped to an output vector of length 3. So after training the ANN should know that if it for example gets an input vector of length 3 it should produce an output vector of length 3.

It this possible with keras? And how would a custom loss function for such a mapping look like. Maybe something like this (assuming y_true is a vector with 2 dimensions [Batchsize, 5]:

```
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    for i in range (0, len(y_true)):
        for j in range (0, len(y_true[i]):
           if y_true[i][j] ==d:
             squared_difference = 0
        else: 
             squared_difference = tf.square(y_true[i][j] - y_pred[i][j])
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = y_true != d
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((y_true - y_pred) ** 2 * tf.cast(mask, dtype=y_true.dtype), axis=-1)
    return loss
```

**P.S.**
It would be probably better to pass length into loss like

```py
y_true = {"value": value, "length": length}
```

and use
[`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask). For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

max_length = 5

def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_value = y_true["value"]
    y_true_length = y_true["length"]
    
    mask = tf.sequence_mask(lengths=y_true_length, maxlen=max_length)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((y_true_value - y_pred) ** 2 * tf.cast(mask, dtype=y_pred.dtype), axis=-1)
    return loss 

batch_size = 2
y_true={
    "value": tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, max_length]), 
    "length": tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch_size], maxval=max_length, dtype=tf.int32) + 1
}
y_pred=tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, max_length])

my_loss_fn(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your answer. Why and where shall I use `y_true = {"value": value, "length": length}` as you suggested? And what do you mean by "mask". Why shall I use it?

Comment: @PeterBe, see the answer update

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your answer and effort. To be honest, I still don't know what to do if I want to use a customized loss function. I have a model with RNNs and have the following lines at the end
`model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
                                history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))`. I want to fit the `X_train, Y_train` using the `loss="mean_squared_error"`. But now the loss function should not consider dummys

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your comments. Any comment on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: @PeterBe Feel free to use any guides about custom loss function in Keras. For example, [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_losses). Make sure your dataset is also prepared with proper dict labels if you decided to use the last option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Alexey. I really appreciate it. If I would like to use the Root-Mean-Squarred-Error for the loss function but only consider the values that are not indicated as dummies, how would the python code in Keras look like? Can I directly use your suggested code for this?

Comment: This depend on your framework. One example with custom loss is given the guide cited above.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your answer. What kind of loss function is your suggested code actually calculating? Is it calculating the root-mean-squared-error but just for the data that does not have any dummy variables (which was bascially my core question)? If so, I could directly use it.

Comment: The first version of `my_loss_fn` in my suggested code coincides exactly with your  `my_loss_fn` up to conversion from naive python to tensorflow. Theoretically you can use this function in keras `compile` method, provides `d` is defined somewhere and the detaset is correctly passed to keras `fit` methos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I will try to use your code. I upvoted and accepted your answer.